# How to make Jet - Responsive Megamenu compatible with Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, megamenu

Is Jet - Responsive Megamenu compatible with Wordpress? 
If not how can i make it work with Wordpress menu system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you have the code that makes the menu to work on Wordpress. It is tested on Wordpress 4.3 but I think it works on Wordpress 3.2+ (I'm not 100% sure).

```
<?php
/* Put this script inside header.php in Wordpress theme folder */

class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
        function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
                $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown\">\n";
        }
}

$menuSettings = array(
        'container'       => 'div',
        'menu_class'      => 'jetmenu yellow', //change this to whatever classes you need for your menu
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s dropdown">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 3, //the number of submenus + 1
        'walker'          => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu()
);

wp_nav_menu( $menuSettings ); //This script displays the menu. Please put it where you want it to display the menu.

?>
```

I hope this solves someone's problem.